# Combine two find commands

Tags: bash, find

I'm looking to find the folder named - `secrets`, under `/home/build`, if found, check if it has a tar.gz file under it, recursively.

I tried some thing like below but it didn't work, how can I fix this ?

```
find -type d \( -name "secrets" \) -exec find . -type f -name "*.tar.gz"
```

OS - MacOS

Comment: `find /home/build -type f -path */secrets/*.tar.gz`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, yes, but quote the pattern so the shell doesn't expand it first.

Comment: @glennjackman Ooops, you're right, of course, I should have quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work :

```
find -type d \( -name "secrets" \) -execdir find {} -type f -name "*.tar.gz" \;
```